# UIScrollView Using Only Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard, autolayout, constraints

I know this question has been answered before, many times, but my use case seems to be just different enough from all of them that I can't quite figure it out.

#### My Problem

I have a scroll view that is not the same size as its superview. The scroll view has 1 subview that is the same size as it, but it needs to be able to be pinch-zoomed.

#### Attempted Tutorials:

(1) - [Apple's Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) - This is done only with code and the examples show only full screen scroll views.

(2) - [Natasha The Robot's Article](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/) - This was a really well written article but I could not get it to work for me. I think it's due to the fact that her scroll view is full screen.

(3) - [Happy Coding Blog Article](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/ios-how-to-use-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-pure-auto-layout/) - Another full screen scroll view

... and lots other tutorials that were very similar to these

#### My requirements

- My scroll view needs to be full width
- My scroll view needs to be 40pt from the top and have a 1:1 aspect ratio
- My scroll view needs to have one subview that is the exact same size of it but can be pinch-zoomed (aka content size = scroll view size)

I don't think that the size of the scroll view should impact anything, but it appears to.

#### What I have tried

As all the tutorials above recommended, I have only a single subview of the scroll view and have aptly named it "Content View".

- View Controller
  |-View
    |-ScrollView
       |-ContentView
          |-ZoomableView

Here is a picture of my constraints:

[image: Constraints]

As you can see, I have an equal width set up from the "Grid" (Zoomable view) to the view controller's view. I've also tried adding an equal width of the content view and the VC's view.

#### My question

I know I can get this to work with an explicit width and height, but I know I should be able to get it by setting the width equal to the view's width and height equal to the view's width as well (AKA 1:1 aspect ratio). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I ran into the same problem in the past. What I end up doing was adding a "container" view and use it to set up my width and height equality constraints instead of the view controller's view.

[image: Layout]

This setup will produce what you want I think: a scrollview with 1 subview that can be pinch-zoomed in the view controller's view (grey in the screenshot) but with a top margin of 40pt.

[image]

Comment: Nailed it. It's adding the content view with equal, unambiguous constraints to the content view's superview.